# Ubuntu 16.04 sometimes does not apply theme at startup

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm, icon-themes

I have the arc theme installed and the numix circle icon pack. Sometimes, when I boot up the system, the desktop looks like this (note also how bad the text looks):

[image: desktop at startup]

However, if I do from the terminal `sudo service lightdm restart`, everything is normal as expected:

[image: after restarting lightdm]

This didn't happen some days ago, maybe it's something I installed. This also happened sporadically on 14.04, but now is more frequent.

How can I solve this, or at least how can I try to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Same problem here. Icons back to stock and cannot be changed at all. Weird

Comment: `sudo service lightdm restart` fixed mine. I also experience this frequently