# Ubuntu 16.04 – theme does not load at boot up

Tags: boot, 16.04, themes

I 'm having a problem with Ubuntu 16.04, on Asus UX303LA.
I currently use the *Arc theme* but **sometimes**, when I boot up, the theme does not load properly and the environment looks like the *Ambience theme* (with a wrong font...).

This is how it looks like:

[image]

and this is how it should look

[image]

I can't find any kind of "regularity": sometimes it happens, sometimes not. Most of the times (let say, 4 out of 5) it works properly. To solve the problem it's enough to log out, but it's annoying...

Maybe it's related, maybe not, but (again) **sometimes** (say 1 out of 10), when I shut down, it takes 60-90 secs to have the system turned off, while usually a few seconds are enough (I replaced the HD with a SSD).

I know that it seems confusing, but at the moment I can't be more specific :(

Comment: it fails to load on the first login everytime now for me. same issue here http://askubuntu.com/questions/773536/ubuntu-16-04-sometimes-does-not-apply-theme-at-startup?rq=1

Comment: running `setsid unity && killall nautilus` in the terminal is the workaround I use for now.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it's better than log-out and log-in...

Comment: Similar symptoms here, arc, and other themes fail once in a while. Regarding that long shut down delay, I can see the item causing the slowdown (I disabled Plymouth to see it.) I can not remember right now what it is, but it runs a timer to 1min 30sec exactly before shutting down.